# Rotating Derived Objects in hierarchy scales them?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For an assignment I was told to experiment with the Unity hierarchy by making an amusement ride. I created a surface that moves up and down that works fine. When I add new objects to the surface that moves up and down and attempt to rotate them they also scale at the same time. I'm not sure why this happens. I have tried making them outside of the root object then adding them in but it does the same thing. If someone could give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they scale right in the moment when you add them to the surface, then you probably scaled the surface before. In an object hierarchy all objects inherit the transformations of their parents.

You can avoid that by creating your tree with empty objects and only attach the visible objects as leafs.
Instead of doing it this way (which will result in the sub-objects beeing scaled according to the scale of the surface):

```
Surface
+SubObject 1
+SubObject 2
```

You can do it that way:

```
EmptyObject (scale 1)
+Surface
+SubObject 1
+SubObject 2
```

That should solve your problem